# HTML5 Geo Location in mobile phone with no gps

Tags: html, mobile, geolocation

Scenario: I have a nokia 5233 which doesn't have a GPS or WiFi. I installed Opera Mobile web browser which supports HTML5. I tried html5 geolocation in opera mobile. I was stunned it pointed the exact location of my phone. Not approximate location its a accurate location.. It was like it used GPS to find my location but the phone doesn't have a GPS. I used network data connection to load the page.

My questions:

1. How does the browser able to find my accurate location without GPS.
2. Can i use the same method in an application i develop to find the exact location of the user.

Comment: Can you be more precise about how accurate it is - to ~5 meters like GPS?  Is this in an urban or rural area? Have you watched to see how accuracy changes if you're moving (car/bus/train).

Comment: @Kevin It just pointed exactly at my house. And while am on the way to work. I tried it again when the signal was red. It was again perfect...!!

Answer (score 2):

Does your phone support wifi? Google, Apple and a company called Skyhook all run databases of wireless routers (often in addition to two other points of reference, gps and cell towers).

Each router has a unique (and non-changing) MAC address. When your phone checks in, it sends a list of all the MACs for WiFi APs it can "see." Based on the database (which is updated thanks to you and everyone else) they can pretty accurately pinpoint where you are based on the wireless BSSIDs around you.

For more info, check out [this article](http://www.forbes.com/forbes/2010/0830/e-gang-ted-morgan-skyhook-wireless-google-location-everything.html) I wrote on Skyhook.

Answer (score 2):

1. Your phone is triangulating itself based on cell tower signals.  It can be pretty accurate.
2. For people's phones that support it and allow you to geolocate them, yes.

Comment: I read a article about triangulating i can get all the required parameter except one "timing_advance" there is no documentation in nokia developers forum about that.  How opera does it..?

Answer (score 0):

Your navigator( opera ) support HTML5 sins it can get your current position.
The navigator can user multiple methods to get your position ( your wifi , mapping your ip address to a location from your Internet Provider , triangulation for mobile phones ...)
as i know you cant know or specify the method your browser uses to get your position.
Most probably your navigator is using triangulation because you have no wifi, now GPS.